# Does rsample::bootstraps store data rather than just row indices?

Tags: r, tidymodels, rsample

I'm trying to understand why the `rsample::bootstraps` function apparently stores the entire data set for each bootstrap sample. I was expecting the function would just store the dataset once, along with the bootstrap indices for each resample. In the following you can see the basic structure, which is repeated for each resample:

```r
> set.seed(1)
> test <- rsample::bootstraps(mtcars[, 1:3], times = 2)
> str(test)
bootstraps [2 × 2] (S3: bootstraps/rset/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ splits:List of 2
  ..$ :List of 4
  .. ..$ data  :'data.frame':   32 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  .. .. ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  .. .. ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
  .. ..$ in_id : int [1:32] 25 4 7 1 2 29 23 11 14 18 ...
  .. ..$ out_id: logi NA
  .. ..$ id    : tibble [1 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ id: chr "Bootstrap1"
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "rsplit" "boot_split"
  ..$ :List of 4
  .. ..$ data  :'data.frame':   32 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. .. ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  .. .. ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  .. .. ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
  .. ..$ in_id : int [1:32] 25 12 15 1 20 3 6 10 10 6 ...
  .. ..$ out_id: logi NA
  .. ..$ id    : tibble [1 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ id: chr "Bootstrap2"
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "rsplit" "boot_split"
 $ id    : chr [1:2] "Bootstrap1" "Bootstrap2"
 - attr(*, "times")= num 2
 - attr(*, "apparent")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "strata")= logi FALSEbootstraps [1 × 2] (S3:
```

The `$data` item appears to be repeated for additional resamples and the resample indices which vary are stored in `in_id`. The obvious cost is that the size of the object grows in proportion to the data size times the number of resamples. The size of a single resample from `object.size(test)` is 7800 bytes. For 200 resamples it's 1236824 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not repeated every time for each resample; you can [see an example of this in the README for the rsample package](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/). The original data is not modified; R does not make a copy.

There *is* some RAM overhead for each resample and mtcars is a little bit small to be able to understand this well, so let's look at a bigger dataset, such as the Ames housing dataset (look at the README for a different example):

```r
library(rsample)
library(lobstr)
data(ames, package = "modeldata")

obj_size(ames)
#> 1,042,736 B

set.seed(123)
boots <- bootstraps(ames, times = 50)
obj_size(boots)
#> 1,670,760 B

## what is the object size per resample?
obj_size(boots)/nrow(boots)
#> 33,415.2 B

## what is the relative size of the bootstrap object compared to the original?
as.numeric(obj_size(boots)/obj_size(ames))
#> [1] 1.602285
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Much, much less than 50! The bootstrap object is much less than 50 times bigger in memory than the original dataset.

Notice that I used [lobstr](https://lobstr.r-lib.org/) to compare the sizes instead of `object.size()`. The reason is because `object.size()` [does not entirely include the size of all environments in objects and is less accurate overall](https://lobstr.r-lib.org/reference/obj_size.html). If you've ever tried to measure the RAM of objects in R using `object.size()` and felt confused by why it didn't match up with what your OS was saying, this is probably why. Using `lobstr::obj_size()` can solve this problem.

Comment: Super-helpful, thanks. I just verified in my real use case that `object.size` does show a proportional increase. With 1000 bootstraps, an object that is 18kb grows to more than 17mb, but using `obj_size` only grows to 1mb. Why does `str(boots)` make it *appear* that the object is duplicated? It looks as if it's in every resample which obviously makes no sense. And why is the "mismeasurement" of `object.size` proprtional in this way? The consistency between `str` and `object.size` is why I posted.

Comment: What is stored in an rsample object is a reference to the original data, not the whole data, and unfortunately `object.size()` isn't smart enough to measure that correctly. It [does the same thing for ALTREP objects](https://github.com/r-lib/lobstr/issues/21). When you call `str()`, it gets what is actually at the reference, not the reference.